# RabbitMQ - subscribe to message type as it gets created

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I'm wondering how to implement the following: producer creates tasks for multiple sites, there's a bunch of consumers that should process these tasks one by one, but only talking to 1 site with concurrency of 1, without starting a new task for this site before the previous one ended. This way slow site would be processed slowly, and the fast ones - fast (as opposed by slow sites taking up all the worker capacity).

Ideally a site would be processed only by one worker at a time, being replaced by another worker if it dies. This seems like a task for exclusive queues, but apparently there's no easy way to list and subscribe to new queues. What is the proper way to achieve such results with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have things the wrong way round.  For workers you have 1 or more producers sending to 1 exchange.  The exchange has 1 queue (you can send directly to the queue, but all that is really doing is going via a default exchange, I prefer to be explicit).  All consumers connect to the single queue and read off tasks in turn.  You should set the queue to require messages to be ACKed before removing them. That way if a process dies it should be returned to the queue and picked up by the next consumer/worker.

Comment: So how do I only process one message per site at a time?

Comment: you use basicQos(1) have you had a look at this http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html it should explain all you need to know